# How to programmatically use the new Windows Copilot?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to programmatically use Windows Copilot from a Windows app ?

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "programmatically use"?

Comment: from code rather than through manual or user-interface-based methods

Comment: Using Microsoft Spy++ to identify the Windows Copilot window, it appears "Intermediate D3D Window" but the input box seems not to provide a handle that Spy++ may detect

Comment: FindWindow( NULL, "Preview" ) returns zero. How to reach that Preview window handle ?

Comment: https://betanews.com/2023/08/29/microsoft-is-testing-os-level-plugins-for-windows-copilot-in-windows-11/   thanks to Rafael Rivera @WithinRafael for pointing this

Comment: Using WindowFromPoint() we can identify a Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND used classname for Windows Copilot and checking its parent we get a Chrome_WidgetWin_1

Comment: so it seems as Windows Copilot uses HTML, same as vscode, and it is rendered in a Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND window. How to access the HTML rendered there ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to run Windows Copilot and send it a message from our apps:

```
ShellExecute( 0, "open", "microsoft-edge://?ux=copilot&tcp=1&source=taskbar" )
SysWait( 1 )
CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ):SendKeys( "tell me latest news~" )
```

Answer (score 0):

One step further. Now we need to find out when Copilot ends answering:

```
   ShellExecute( 0, "open", "microsoft-edge://?ux=copilot&tcp=1&source=taskbar" )
   SysWait( 5 )
   CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ):SendKeys( "what time is it ?~" )
   SysWait( 15 )
   CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ):SendKeys( "{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}~" )
   MsgInfo( TClipBoard():GetText() )
```